# Poll the database using spring Integration poller using jpa

Tags: spring-integration

In our application , we have to use a spring poller to fetch the records from mysql db in every 'n' seconds and send the data to a web-service system and get the success or failure confirmation from the web-service system. Hibernate is our orm.

I am new to spring & web-service, please help me on how to develop this.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jpa.html

I was referring the above link

```
<int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter channel="inboundChannelAdapterOne"  
                   `enter code here`
    <int:poller fixed-rate="2000" >
      <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>``
    </int:poller>
</int-jpa:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

This I have added in my configuration.xml file..Is this is the right way for implement this scenario, can someone help me by giving a simple example of jpa:inbound-channel-adapter implementaion?

Comment: This is not a well-constructed question. Did you try it? Did it not work? If not, exactly what problem are you having? Follow the documentation; if you have an issue you can't resolve; then ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some samples about JPA in Spring Integration [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/jpa).